# SQLITE record not updating

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Ok so this is my code to create the database , create a skelenton user (create_user) , update f_name field (save_fName)

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE UserData (
        id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
        user_id int,
        f_name text,
        phone_no text,
        f_code int,
        Recording_url text,
        rrt_number int,
        c_cex int,
        c_y int,
        nt_number int,
       x_pin int
    )""")

def save_fName(sf_N, userid):
   c.execute(f"UPDATE UserData SET f_name = '''+{sf_N}+''' WHERE user_id = '''+{userid}+'''")
   conn.commit()

def create_user(userid):
   sql = f"Insert into UserData values(0,{userid},'Notavailable','Notavailable',0,'Notavailable',0,0,0,0,0)"
   c.execute(sql)
   conn.commit()
```

I have tried updating into phone_no field using exactly the same code as save_fName function only with different parameters and that works just fine but when i try to update a record at the f_name field using save_fName it doesn't just update, no errors but it stays at 'Notavailable'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your request is badly formed and not secure. use tuples and question marks

```
def save_fName(sf_N, userid):
   c.execute("UPDATE UserData SET f_name = ? WHERE user_id = ?", (sf_N, userid))
   conn.commit()
```